# Methods of speeding up a MySQL Query which has 12 subqueries

Tags: mysql, performance

The following query returns the correct data but I'd like to see if there's a better way of doing this.  The query should return the number of cases for each month within a 12 month period where a record exists within the past 2 months.  The idea is to get number of accounts that ordered during the month in question and at least one of the previous 2 months. Also, please note that every value in the table for data_date will always be the 1st of the month.

```
SELECT 
sum( 
        case 
            WHEN    a.data_date = '2013-03-01'
                    and exists( 
                            select 1 from sales mth1 
                            where mth1.client_id = a.client_id
                            and 
                                    data_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' 
                                    and 
                                    '2013-02-01' 

                    ) 
            then case_qty 
            ELSE 0 END
) AS M1 , 
sum( 
        case 
                WHEN a.data_date = '2013-04-01' 
                        and exists( 
                                select 1 from sales mth2 
                                where mth2.client_id = a.client_id 
                                and mth2.data_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' 
                                        and 
                                        '2013-03-01' 
                        ) 
                then case_qty 
                ELSE 0 END
    ) AS M2 , 
    sum( case WHEN a.data_date = '2013-05-01' and exists( select 1 from sales mth3 where mth3.client_id = a.client_id and mth3.data_date BETWEEN '2013-03-01' and '2013-04-01' )  then case_qty ELSE 0 END) AS M3 , 
    sum( case WHEN a.data_date = '2013-06-01' and exists( select 1 from sales mth4 where mth4.client_id = a.client_id and mth4.data_date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' and '2013-05-01' )  then case_qty ELSE 0 END) AS M4 , 
    sum( case WHEN a.data_date = '2013-07-01' and exists( select 1 from sales mth5 where mth5.client_id = a.client_id and mth5.data_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' and '2013-06-01' )  then case_qty ELSE 0 END) AS M5 , 
    sum( case WHEN a.data_date = '2013-08-01' and exists( select 1 from sales mth6 where mth6.client_id = a.client_id and mth6.data_date BETWEEN '2013-06-01' and '2013-07-01' )  then case_qty ELSE 0 END) AS M6 , 
    sum( case WHEN a.data_date = '2013-09-01' and exists( select 1 from sales mth7 where mth7.client_id = a.client_id and mth7.data_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' and '2013-08-01' )  then case_qty ELSE 0 END) AS M7 , 
    sum( case WHEN a.data_date = '2013-10-01' and exists( select 1 from sales mth8 where mth8.client_id = a.client_id and mth8.data_date BETWEEN '2013-08-01' and '2013-09-01' )  then case_qty ELSE 0 END) AS M8 , 
    sum( case WHEN a.data_date = '2013-11-01' and exists( select 1 from sales mth9 where mth9.client_id = a.client_id and mth9.data_date BETWEEN '2013-09-01' and '2013-10-01' )  then case_qty ELSE 0 END) AS M9 , 
    sum( case WHEN a.data_date = '2013-12-01' and exists( select 1 from sales mth10 where mth10.client_id = a.client_id and mth10.data_date BETWEEN '2013-10-01' and '2013-12-01' )  then case_qty ELSE 0 END) AS M10 , 
    sum( case WHEN a.data_date = '2014-01-01' and exists( select 1 from sales mth11 where mth11.client_id = a.client_id and mth11.data_date BETWEEN '2013-11-01' and '2013-12-01' )  then case_qty ELSE 0 END) AS M11  
FROM sales as a 
INNER JOIN Products AS P ON P.product_id = a.product_id  
WHERE a.client_id IN ('123') 
AND a.data_date BETWEEN '2013-03-01' AND '2013-12-01' AND a.case_qty > 0;
```

[Here's a screen shot of the explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckTLw.png)

[Here's a screen shot of the indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqCDC.png)

Answer (score 0):

change

data_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' and '2013-02-01' 
to
 data_date in ('2013-01-01', '2013-01-02',.....,...'2013-02-01' )

but i would turn this whole query into sum cases then use a wrapper to pull out the accounts i need.

Comment: That's a good idea about removing the between.  I'm not sure what you mean by turning the query into sum cases?  It's already sum cases.

Answer (score 0):

From your query it seems like you want the years sales for a product in an entire year. Or something to that affect. So from your data you are almost trying to create a pivot. I had a simlar problem and solved it like this

```
select
   p.product_id,
   s.client_id,
   sum(case when DATE_FORMAT(a.data_date,'%Y%m') in (201301) then ifnull(case_qty,0) else 0 end) period1,
   sum(case when DATE_FORMAT(a.data_date,'%Y%m') in (201301, 201302) then ifnull(case_qty,0) else 0 end) period2,
   sum(case when DATE_FORMAT(a.data_date,'%Y%m') in (201301, 201302, 201303) then ifnull(case_qty,0) else 0 end) period3,
   sum(case when DATE_FORMAT(a.data_date,'%Y%m') in (201302, 201303, 201304) then ifnull(case_qty,0) else 0 end) period4,
   sum(case when DATE_FORMAT(a.data_date,'%Y%m') in (201303, 201304, 201305) then ifnull(case_qty,0) else 0 end) period5,
   .
   .
   .
   up to period12
from
   sales s
where
   a.data_date between '2013-03-01' and '2013-12-31' and
   s.client_id = some_value
group by
   p.product_id,
   s.client_id
```

Note that the performance of the query has increased drastically since you are only doing a single scan of your sales table (depending on what's in your where clause and indexes). To speed it up you would need indexes on say client_id and data_date for example.

Ideally this query would be run for a report or something where the start and end data is fixed and all the user can change is the year of that date. I wasn't sure if you wanted to group by product_id since in your query you aren't, but you can always remove it to get total per client.

I have adjusted the query based on my understanding in your comments. I am not 100% sure if you can use the keyword 'in' in a case statement. You could alternatively have more case statements.

Comment: This won't work.  I need to to see for example the total cases in March 2013 that also has cases sold in Jan 2013 or Feb 2013.  case 
            WHEN    a.data_date = '2013-03-01'
             and exists( 
                            select 1 from sales mth1 
                            where mth1.client_id = a.client_id
                            and 
                                    data_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' 
                                    and 
                                    '2013-02-01' 

                    ) 
            then case_qty 
            ELSE 0 END
) AS M1 ,

Comment: So you want a year to past two months calculation? So jan = just jan, feb = feb+jan, march = jan, feb, march and so on?

Comment: I have adjusted the query. Not sure if it's exactly what you want. With a bit more information might be able to get you there.